# MonoTouch: Reference Counting Bug in version 5.2.12

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

MonoTouch recently released version 5.2.13 to fix an issue with reference counting in newer versions of iOS.

Running our apps in the newer version of iOS seems to be just fine. We don't use XCode or Interface Builder at all.

What can we do to see if our apps fail the reference counting issue, is there a kind of action, like creating a lot of XYZ or updating ABC that would stress test our apps for the newer version os iOS ?

Comment: Our experience with this issue was that our app would crash almost immediately on iOS 6.  This was resolved by removing `[Connect]` and using `[Outlet]` instead.  Any apps you are still using the old attribute?

Comment: Some older apps with out [Connect] failed instantly, but the newer apps running MonoTouch 5.x and higher seems fine. Most of our apps are MonoTouch.Dialog based. 100% success with MonoTouch 5.2.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your application under XCode's Instruments using:

a) an old version on iOS (e.g. 5.1) and;

b) under a *really new* version of iOS.

Use the application for a while and compare their memory usage (i.e. they should be comparable even if the initial memory usage can vary by iOS version).

Comment: We've now had 100% success with MonoTouch 5.2.13. Good job guys!